LsaLogonUser returning error code 0xC004848c for SmartCard Login
I am calling LsaLogonUser with the KERB_CERTICATE_LOGON struct pointing to a smart card. I am trying to authenticate a certificate with Azure/Entra that is Federated through WS-Fed. I am getting the error code 0xC004848c from LsaLogonUser. This suggests the metadata doesn't contain a required certificate endpoint. Does anyone know what this means and/or what is required?
I've tried setting various x509 certs in the metadata including TokenSigningKeyInfo, but they did not help.

so you got AAD_CLOUDAP_E_HTTP_CERTIFICATE_URI_IS_EMPTY error. are this the same question ?

@RbMm Yes, that is the same question posed by a co-worker working on the same issue. :-)

error inside AADCLOUDAP.DLL. in LogonIdentityNoDeviceAuth or in LogonIdentity. with debugger probably possible exactly research this case
